# yeoman / cssmin - Minimize, but don't concat CSS files

Tags: css, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm working on a webapp (using the yeoman webapp generator) and I've got two scss base files, my standard (main.scss) and my old-ie (main-old-ie.scss) - using this technique: http://jakearchibald.github.io/sass-ie/

Is there a way to have usemin minimize the files, but not concat on build?

Comment: why would someone downvote this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) and then you can pass it options to minimize your sass when it processes it.

Comment: Thanks - yeoman's gruntfile.js already includes Grunt-contrib-compass, so I tacked on some options there. But your answer pointed me in the right direction!